# Qiskit logical to physical qubit mapping

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, compiling

I want to run a simulation using `qasm` with a realistic noise model from a backend, specifying a `coupling_map` as well as an `initial_layout`. I do that via a `QuantumInstance` which in turn is passed to an algorithm. Now, two questions regarding that qubit layout:

1. I know that the transpiler may change the mapping of logical to physical qubits. Furthermore, I pass a circuit to the algorithm as an argument and the algorithm then adds an ancilla qubit to the circuit.
   Is there a way for me to verify the final logical to physical qubit mapping after transpiling?
2. Could that automatic adding of an ancilla cause problems when using `QuantumInstance` with a specific `initial_layout`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the final qubit layout (regarding to your first question), you can look at the circuit `data`. Here is an example:

```
circuit = QuantumCircuit(4, 4)

for i in range(4):
    circuit.x(i)
circuit.measure([0,1,2,3], [0,1,2,3])

    
Circuit_Transpile = transpile(circuit, provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne') , 
                                initial_layout =None, optimization_level=3)

for quantum_register in Circuit_Transpile.data[:circuit.num_qubits]:
    print(quantum_register[1])
```

What you will see as output is something like:

```
[[Qubit(QuantumRegister(15, 'q'), 0)],
 [Qubit(QuantumRegister(15, 'q'), 9)],
 [Qubit(QuantumRegister(15, 'q'), 13)],
 [Qubit(QuantumRegister(15, 'q'), 14)]]
```

The number on the right correspond to the qubit number on the device of your interest. There are other ways to do this as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you elaborate on the alternatives for doing this? The above has two caveats; It does not show the ordering of logical qubits (e.g. `[Qubit(QuantumRegister(15, 'q1'), 9)]`) and, furthermore. gives one such line for every gate in the circuit, making it highly repetitive for longer circuits. I am looking for something like a dictionary logical --> physical qubits, e.g., `{'q0': 0, 'q1': 9, 'q2': 13, 'q3': 14}`.

Comment: The other answer I was thinking of is extracting the qasm code... `print(Circuit_Transpile.qasm())` but that does not give you what you want...

Comment: @KAJ226 How do I know which logical qubit is the physical qubit on the right being mapped to? Also, what are the other ways to do this?